# Can you unpack a list of values into variables in a With expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions, scoping, assignment, variable

For instance, if I am trying to draw a graph with 5 vertices labeled a through e, and I want to draw edges connecting a and b, a and c, a and d, a and e, b and c, b and d, and c and e, I would run the following code.

```
{a, b, c, d, e} = CirclePoints[5]
Graphics[{
  {PointSize@Medium, Point[{a, b, c, d, e}]},
  Line[{
    {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {a, e},
    {b, c}, {b, d},
    {c, e}}]
}]
```

Which results in this graphic [image: graph]
<sub>(source: [gdurl.com](http://gdurl.com/noVC))</sub>

However, this becomes frustrating as `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are not bound to the `Graphics` call. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
With[{
    {a, b, c, d, e} = CirclePoints[5]
}, Graphics[{
      {PointSize@Medium, Point[{a, b, c, d, e}]},
      Line[{
        {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {a, e},
        {b, c}, {b, d},
        {c, e}}]
   }]
]
```

However, this results in an error

`"Local variable specification {{a,b,c,d,e}=CirclePoints[5]} contains {a,b,c,d,e}=CirclePoints[5], which is an assignment to {a,b,c,d,e}; only assignments to symbols are allowed."`

which makes sense, given that `With` does not have the desired capability, and neither do `Block` and `Module`.

So, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Won't Thread directly solve your problem?

Comment: How so? I don't know if threaded assignments work in `With`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The 1st argument of `With` does not allow destructuring. It only accepts a list of simple assignments.

I would rewrite the example you give as

```
Module[{a, b, c, d, e},
  {a, b, c, d, e} = CirclePoints[5]; 
  Graphics[
    {{PointSize @ Medium, Point[{a, b, c, d, e}]}, 
     Line[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {a, e}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, e}}]}]]
```

Comment: Clever. I figured the answer would involve multiple statements if there was no elegant way that I just didn't know of. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
Function[{a, b, c, d, e}, 
 Graphics[{{PointSize@Medium, Point[{a, b, c, d, e}]}, 
 Line[{{a,b}, {a,c}, {a,d}, {a,e}, {b,c}, {b,d}, {c, e}}]}]]@@CirclePoints[5]
```

I used a `Function` to localize the variables and then applied it to the desired points with `@@`.